# onsubmit returns false, but submit executes anyway

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

I'm lost again. I have a registration form with three JS functions that produce the desired output when called by onchange from my html form. So they produce a BS alert while the user is filling out the form. These are the three functions:

To check password length:

```
function checkPassword() {
    var x = document.registerForm;
    var wachtwoord = x.wachtwoord.value;
    var errMsgHolder = document.getElementById("message");
    if (wachtwoord.length < 3 || wachtwoord.length >30) {
        errMsgHolder.innerHTML =
            '<div class="alert alert-warning"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a><strong>Let op!</strong> Kies een wachtwoord van minimaal 3 en maximaal 30 tekens.</div>';
        setTimeout(function () {document.getElementById("message").innerHTML =''; }, 5000);
        return false;
    }
}
```

To check if the 2 passwords match:

```
function checkPasswordsMatch() {
    var x = document.registerForm;
    var wachtwoord = x.wachtwoord.value;
    var herhaal_wachtwoord = x.herhaal_wachtwoord.value;
    var errMsgHolder = document.getElementById("message");
    if (wachtwoord !== herhaal_wachtwoord) {
        errMsgHolder.innerHTML =
            '<div class="alert alert-warning"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a><strong>Let op!</strong> Wachtwoorden komen niet overeen.</div>';
            return false;
    }
}
```

To check if username already exists (ajax call via php to database):

```
function checkBestaandeGebruikersnaam(){
var x = document.registerForm;
var gebruikersnaam = x.gebruikersnaam.value;
var errMsgHolder = document.getElementById("message");
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if(request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) { 
      if(request.responseText == "1") {
            errMsgHolder.innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-warning"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a><strong>Let op!</strong> Die gebruikersnaam is al bezet, kies een andere gebruikersnaam.</div>';
      return false;
      }
      else {
          errMsgHolder.innerHTML = '';
      }
    } else {
      errMsgHolder.innerHTML = 'An error occurred during your request: ' +  request.status + ' ' + request.statusText;
    } 
  }
request.open("POST", "core/functions/checkBestaandeGebruikersnaam.php", true);
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.send("gebruikersnaam="+gebruikersnaam);  
}
```

But these functions just show an alert and don't prevent a user from submitting a form with incorrect data. So I want to revisit these functions when the user submits. To do that I have the following line in my HTML register form:

```
<form action="register.php" onsubmit="return validate()" name="registerForm" method="post" class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-0">
```

Then in JS I have the following function:

```
function validate() {
var errMsgHolder = document.getElementById("message");
if(checkPassword() === false ) {
    errMsgHolder.innerHTML =
            '<div class="alert alert-warning"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a><strong>Let op!</strong> Kies een wachtwoord van minimaal 3 en maximaal 30 tekens.</div>';
            return false;
} else if(checkPasswordsMatch() === false){
    errMsgHolder.innerHTML =
            '<div class="alert alert-warning"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a><strong>Let op!</strong> Wachtwoorden komen niet overeen.</div>';
            return false;
} else if(checkBestaandeGebruikersnaam() === false){
    errMsgHolder.innerHTML = 
            '<div class="alert alert-warning"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a><strong>Let op!</strong> Die gebruikersnaam is al bezet, kies een andere gebruikersnaam.</div>';
            return false;
}
```

When I test this it works for `checkPassword()` and `checkPasswordsMatch()`. Meaning I get the expected BS alerts and the submission of the form is cancelled. But when I test the `checkBestaandeGebruikersnaam()` it does not. It briefly shows the BS alert, but then it continues to my register.php file. So for some reason it disregards the returned 'false' in onsubmit and submits anyway.

I can't get my head around it. Why is it doing this one differently. Can anyone shed some light on the issue?

Edit: I have followed the link and spent the rest of the day trying to grasp the concept of callback functions. I think I have it now, but my problem is not solved. So I must still be doing something wrong.

Since the problem is obviously with the way I return false from the function `checkBestaandeGebruikersnaam()` I will only list the changes to that function. I have the following code now:

HTML:

```
onchange="callAjax(checkBestaandeGebruikersnaam)"
```

JavaScript main function:

```
function callAjax(callback){
var gebruikersnaam = document.registerForm.gebruikersnaam.value;
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if(request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) { 
        callback(request.responseText);
    } else {
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = 'An error occurred during your request: ' +  request.status + ' ' + request.statusText;
    } 
  }
request.open("POST", "core/functions/checkBestaandeGebruikersnaam.php", true);
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.send("gebruikersnaam="+gebruikersnaam); 
}
```

JavaScript callback function:

```
function checkBestaandeGebruikersnaam(result) {
if(result == "1") {
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-warning"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a><strong>Let op!</strong> Die gebruikersnaam is al bezet, kies een andere gebruikersnaam.</div>';
    return false;
}
else {
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = '';
}
}
```

Can someone tell me if I am using the callback functionality correctly? It does perform as expected (on the onchange event).

The function `validate()` still doesn't work for `checkBestaandeGebruikersnaam()` though. It still executes, even if `checkBestaandeGebruikersnaam() === false`. What have I done wrong now? Please enlighten me and thanks for your time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1):

`checkBestaandeGebruikersnaam` never returns `false`.  The `onreadystatechange` callback function does, but that is executed asynchronously.  So `checkBestaandeGebruikersnaam` executes and returns (an undefined value) immediately and the `return false;` that you seem to be expecting happens sometime later and is ignored.  Matteo suggested a link for returning the response from an asynchronous call, which you should check out, it is on the right track to solving your problem.  In modern JavaScript I would suggest handling this with a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) chain.

Another way to solve this would be to explicitly submit the form from javascript whenever the required conditions pass - e.g. from within the `onreadystatechange` method, so you don't have to worry about the asynchronous state control.  The form element has a `submit` method you can call.

Comment: Good answer. The OP also needs to disable form submission while waiting for the callback.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove the onsubmit property of the form, and instead use the 
Submit button's onclick property:

> onclick="return validate();"

This would work.
Thanks!

Comment: Not a good suggestion. Forms can be submitted without clicking the submit button, so a function relying on that may not be called when the form is submitted. And this does not address the fundamental issue of the asynchronous function.